# django templates decimal separator with safe tag

Tags: django, localization, django-templates

view.py

```
def a(request)
  a=3.222
  c=1.555
  if a>5:
    b='<h1>%0.3f</h1>' % (a)
  else
    b='%0.3f' % (a)
  content={'a':b, 'c':c}
  return render(request, 'a.html', context)
```

a.html

```
{{ a|safe }}
{{ c }}
```

In PL loc. decimal separator is ','
C value is printed as 1,555 - nice, but b is printed as 3.222 because of using safe which i have to use because of html tags.
How can i make all float values separated with ',' ?

Comment: Show us your real code. What's is b/ What b could be in your real code?

Comment: a is db_value1/db_value2 if db_value3 is 1 then i add <span class="error">%0.3f</span> tag to b value. Real code is really complicated and this example is essence what my problem is. I don't want to move if a>5: to template code.

Comment: You can't change the behavior of the safe tag. If you can't move all code to template,can you separate only a from other content,and render it in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you problem is in any way connected to using `safe`. It's just a case of python string formating (that you use in your view) not being location-aware. You could try using [locale.format()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.format) instead, which is intended as a locale-aware alternative.

But it is not a good practice to put HTML into your views anyway. So I would move formating logic to your template:

view.py

```
def a(request)
  a=3.222
  c=1.555
  content={'a':b, 'c':c}
  return render(request, 'a.html', context)
```

a.html

```
{% if a>5 %}
    <b>{{ a }}</b>
{% else %}
    {{ a }}
{% endif %}

{{ c }}
```